# Can't Solve Segfault Error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This isn't all of the program, but it doesn't run past this function. It seems to have the segfault near the fscanf statement, but I don't think that's what's causing the error. I really don't see anything that could cause the segfault error, but I'm an amateur and probably missed something. All of the printf statements are for debugging purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10  

struct point2d_def
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
typedef struct point2d_def point2d;

void fill(char str[], point2d P[])
{

    FILE *ifp = NULL;
    ifp = fopen(str, "r");
    int i = 0;

    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s for reading\n", ifp);
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &P[i].x, &P[i].y);
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    printf("Fill function passed\n");
    return;
    printf("Blorp");
}
```

Comment: How is the array P declared?

Comment: arguments cannot be arrays, use pointers instead

Comment: How is `P` allocated? Probably you allocated it with `N` (10) entries, but you're writing to 11 locations in the loop with the `fscanf`.

Comment: How is `fill` called?

Comment: `ifp` is `NULL` (because of the `if` condition) in `printf("Could not open %s for reading\n", ifp);`. Nonsense. Also passing `FILE*` where `char*` is expected will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try using your debugger to see in which line the error occurs.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz In my program it's called in main like this: fill(argv[1], P);

Answer (score 0):

first you are declaring `P[N]` inside the func, and  receiving `P` in the parameters.

second, you are writing to 11 slots instead of 10:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &P[i].x, &P[i].y);
}
```

remove the `=`...

Comment: I've changed everything to match your answer and I still have a segmentation fault; is there anything else that I could have messed up or didn't include in my code?

Comment: Pleae show the part you are declaring `P`, and the line you call the `fill` func